# Where does .link() function belong to and what is data from property

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates

I want to know the following flow and what plugins they are using?

I tried all kind of debugging with tools and all , can someone please explin

Not asking for any code , if you can tell me the plugins thats enough.

json object

```
 var movies = [
        { Name: "English2", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
        { Name: "English3", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
        { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
    ];


<table id="tableID">
</table>
```

// what is this link and can you please tell me what plugin .link() belongs to..i checked in jquery and its available there.

```
$("#tableID").link(movies, "#rowTemplate");
```

// what is the property data-getfrom???

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <tr>
    <td data-getfrom="[Name]"></td>
    <td data-getfrom="[ReleaseYear]"></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone could make a plugin and has a function called `link`, but from your content, I think this is what you are finding.

http://api.jquery.com/link/

Comment: thanks for your response , can you tell me what is this property data-getfrom=??

Comment: @kobe I think it is used to relate the template and the data.